# Create Excel CSV template with Papa Parse Angular

Tags: angular, papaparse

I'm trying to create empty excel file(template) with column names only. I'm not sure if it is possible to create such CSV file with Papa Parse(https://www.papaparse.com/), because when there is no data, he puts column names in first row (header) instead of column names.

```
fields=['col1Name','col2Name','col3Name'];
Papa.unparse({
  fields,
  []
}
```

[image: CSV file]

[image: Excel file]

Answer (score 0):

You should set the header property to Paparse to indicate that your content has headers sets on first row. This is explained on the [PapaParse documentation](https://www.papaparse.com/docs)

Following your example, you should use the following snipet:

```
fields=['col1Name','col2Name','col3Name'];
Papa.unparse({
  fields,
  {'header': true},
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did you mean:
Papa.unparse({
      fields},
      {'header': true},
    );

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solution

Comment: Could you elaborate why not is the solution? Can give more advice without any further comment.

Comment: It gives same results as displayed in pic above. It puts my column names in second row.

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this will work.

// Specifying fields and data explicitly

```
var csv = Papa.unparse({
    "fields": ["Column 1", "Column 2" , "Column 3"],
    "data": [

    ]
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solution

Answer (score 0):

For me, delimiting with a ";" corrected the problem.

```
Papa.unparse(
  {
    data: []
    fields: [],
  },
  { delimiter: ';' },
);
```